# Troubles with some Expected Value

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value

Let $\mathbb{X,Y,Z}$ be random variables such that $\mathbb{X}$ has finite expected value and $\mathbb{Y}$ is bounded. Prove that:
$$a)\quad \mathbb{E[Y|Z]} \quad is \quad bounded$$
$$b)\quad \mathbb{E[YE[X|Z]]=\mathbb{E[XE[Y|Z]]}}$$
I have tried to proof both subsections but I think that I'm just closer to the first one:

Let's suposse that $\mathbb{Y,Z}$ are continuous, so:
$$\mathbb{E[Y|Z]}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y\mathbb{P[Y=y|Z]}dy\le k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{P[Y=y|Z]}dy \quad because\quad \mathbb{Y}\quad is\quad bounded$$
$$k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{P[Y=y|Z]}dy = k$$
$$\therefore \mathbb{E[Y|Z]\le k}$$
If $\mathbb{Y,Z}$ are discrete, so:
$$\mathbb{E[Y|Z]}=\sum_{Y}y\mathbb{P[Y=y|Z]}\le k\sum_Y\mathbb{P[Y=y|Z]}=k$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) $Y$ is bounded , we can use [Monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties)  property of conditional expectation,so

\begin{align}
a<&Y<b \\
\mathbb E(a|Z)<&\mathbb E(Y|Z)<\mathbb E(b|Z) \\
a<&\mathbb E(Y|Z)<b
\end{align}

(b) By conditioning on $Z$ and use [Low of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(Y\mathbb E(X|Z))&=\mathbb E \color{blue}{(}\mathbb E\color{red}{(}Y\mathbb E(X|Z)\mid Z\color{red}{)}\color{blue}{)}
\overset{(1)}{=} \mathbb E \color{blue}{(} \mathbb E(X|Z) \mathbb E\color{red}{(}Y\mid Z\color{red}{)}\color{blue}{)}\\
\mathbb E(X\mathbb E(Y|Z))&=\mathbb E \color{blue}{(}\mathbb E\color{red}{(}X\mathbb E(Y|Z)\mid Z\color{red}{)}\color{blue}{)}
\overset{(2)}{=} \mathbb E \color{blue}{(} \mathbb E(Y|Z) \mathbb E\color{red}{(}X\mid Z\color{red}{)}\color{blue}{)}
\end{align}
So both are same.

In (1) and (2) we used the [Pulling out known factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) property of conditional expectation for example for (2)

$$\mathbb E \color{blue}{(}\mathbb E\color{red}{(}X\mathbb E(Y|Z)\mid Z\color{red}{)}\color{blue}{)}=\mathbb E \color{blue}{(}\mathbb E\color{red}{(}X\mathbb g(Z)\mid Z\color{red}{)}\color{blue}{)}=\mathbb E \color{blue}{(}g(Z) \mathbb E\color{red}{(}X \mid Z\color{red}{)}\color{blue}{)}=\mathbb E \color{blue}{(}\mathbb E(Y|Z) \mathbb E\color{red}{(}X \mid Z\color{red}{)}\color{blue}{)}$$